# how to sort array pointers of struct by name?

Tags: c, qsort

I'm trying to sort struct by field 'name', but It don't works :/ 
Can you show or explain me the problem that i didn't see?

```
struct clients {
int id;
char name[27];
};

int comparator(const void* p, const void* q){
return strcmp(((struct list_node*)p)->name,
              ((struct list_node*)q)->name);
}

void sort_by_name(struct list_node *node){

const int length = count_list(node);
struct list_node *arr[length];
int i=0;
while (node)
{
    arr[i]=node;
    node = node->next;
    i++;
}

printf("Before sort:\n");
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    printf("Id = %d, Name = %s\n",
           arr[i]->id, arr[i]->name);
}

qsort(arr, length, sizeof(struct list_node), comparator);

printf("After sort:\n");
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    printf("Id = %d, Name = %s\n",
           arr[i]->id, arr[i]->name);
}

}
```

Result:

```
 Before sort:
 Id = 11, Name = adam
 Id = 20, Name = mati
 Id = 25, Name = zenek
 Id = 28, Name = mat

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005).
```

I use the function in main menu - user have to decide print sorted or not sorted list

Comment: Have you run/stepped it in the debugger?

Comment: I load the structure elements from a file*

Comment: @PaulOgilvie  I didn't yet.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `comparator` and check what qsort passes.

Comment: Why equal? 'i' is variable to operate on array

Comment: I think it's good time to [learn how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Please don't change the question once there are answers posted. I had to do a rollback since your changes invalidated the answer, and now the formatting that someone fixed is back to the original unindented crap. Edit and fix it yourself this time. Posting unindented code is rude to the people helping you for free.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is:

```
qsort(arr, length, sizeof(struct list_node), comparator);
```

You tell `qsort` the array has list nodes, but the array has only *pointers* to list nodes, so:

```
qsort(arr, length, sizeof(struct list_node *), comparator);
```

Comment: I can't be bothered to write my own answer, but `comparator` is also wrong (`p` should be cast to `struct list_node**`).

Comment: I think qsort(arr, length, sizeof arr[0], comparator); is less susceptible to mistakes.